# Symfony jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1

I'm  new in symfony , and dont understand the way how to do ajax request . I read symfony chapter18 for ajax and some google result but I can't explain myself this info  . I need translate myself how I can do someting like this in symfony

```
$(".but_addlap").live("click",function(){


                  $.ajax({
                             url: "laps_edit.php",
                             type: "POST",
                             data: "some data,
                             success: function(result1)
                             {

                                      put some  data from result into div 
                             }
```

in procedure  php I create php file to do some things , get answer and return answer into div . please help me to understand how to do this in Symfony . what I need to write in action,  layout and others ..
I hope my english is not to bad to understand my post .

Comment: Any reason to learn Symfony 1.4 when Symfony 2.0 is out?

Comment: i have my reasons and soon i start to lern version 2 but for now i try to understand 1,4 ..... my friend have old projects written to 1.4 and i need to understand this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code you're showing us is javascript. It happens client-side, so there is no symfony involved here. The only thing that will probably change is the url, which will be more like this : `/index.php/laps/edit`

Comment: yea this is only example.show me how this request coresponding whit file and after put into div results ... what i need to create , what i need to put in action what i need to do its very stupid but i can do this in normal php and im shame myself becose i dont understant logic ....

Comment: i get it :) now all its work. its almost the same like procedure php :)

Comment: Indeed it is. All you had to do was knowing where to put your code ;)